# How to upload files to a different port on the network?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

There is a port with the IP which is `192.168.0.36`. This is a server which will store the files uploaded to the web application, but this is my first time trying to do something like that so I have tried many things to be able to store the files in that server but when it sent the file the application generated the following error:

> Exception during a WebClient request

So I opened the Visual Studio error menu to know more and there is a message which says:

> InnerException = {"The file could not be found 'C: \ Program Files (x86) \ IIS Express \ download.png'. ":" C: \ Program Files (x86) \ IIS Express \ download.png "}

Bt why does it generate this error if I am not accessing the partition C:

This is my code:

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="file_foto" CssClass="file-foto-pf" Style="display: none;" accept="image/*" />

protected void actualizar_foto(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (file_foto.HasFile)
        {
            string Id_Usuario = Request.QueryString["Id_Usuario"].ToString();
            string serverName = @"\\192.168.0.36\\E:\\INTRANET\\";
            string folder = "PRUE\\";
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file_foto.FileName)
            // Upload to Hosted Server.
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri(serverName + folder + fileName);
            webClient.UploadFile(uri, "POST", fileName)
            DCL.Int_Usuarios obj = new DCL.Int_Usuarios();
            obj.Anexo_Foto = uri.ToString();
            obj.Id_Usuario = Convert.ToInt32(Id_Usuario);
            Int_Usuarios_BRL.InsertOrUpdate(obj, 45);
        }
        Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: does your server with the web site - code behind have direct use of the file folders on that other server? You can't for testing type in file:// - since that means to your browser that you are using your local files - and not from the web server. If a user up-loads a file to the web server, then you can do a save-as in your code behind using plane jane windows file path - not a url path.

Comment: well my files are saved on a different server

Comment: Are you using FTP or https or some other means to save to that other server, or does the current running web site have direct rights and use of the file system? that would mean that the current web site and URL don't match nor map to the 2nd server, but you can then do one of two things; create virtual folders to map to that server (this means valid URL's to folders on 2nd server exist). Or use code behind to save, and pull/steam a given file to the end user. This 2nd choice is much more secure, since valid URL's to files never exist as urls, but only code behind can use - which is often good

Comment: So what I am saying? Often a web site needs some huge file folder of documets etc., and the are not on the same folders as the web server. So you can map + create a virtual folder and point it to the other server. That way, the URL's to a base folder will now work. Of course you can only create those virtual folders if the two servers are on the same network. But that's quite much how you share documents and folders to a web site. This means you don't have to place all those folders of files, pictures and documents on the actual web server. and it also means that now valid URL's eixst.

Comment: I use http and yes, they are in the same network thanks for sharing that information I had not found anything on how to do the process, but with what you have helped me I already have a starting point

Comment: It is a royal pain to setup a virtual folder with IIS express edition. With the full additon, it is built in from the UI. From IIS services just open up the folder tree, right click on the root folder and you see create/add virtual folder. For IIs EXPRESS? You have to edit the web config file since we don't have the nice fancy IIS (internet services) UI that makes doing this oh so easy.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure if this is the problem, you could do the following:

```
string serverName = @"file://192.168.0.36/E:/INTRANET/PRUE/";
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file_foto.FileName);
Uri uri = new Uri(Path.Combine(serverName, fileName));
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Could you try to log all the path related values? Maybe the created uri contains a relative path or the IIS root path.

Comment: If the files that I am going to save are going to be from the root path of IIS, that's why because the IP where it is going to be stored